bugged dropdown in laravel 10 jetstream/livewire
image
This is the admin side, when on the home page the theme of the web is white and it is fine there, I'm guessing it's because it is assigned to multiple css tag influencing the same part but I dont know here the files are or what even the name of the file is, how do I fix it
The only part I know that is attached to is a tag <x-app-layout>  </x-app-layout>, it's empty like this but it adds the dropdown menu

This looks like an issue with Tailwind. Make sure that the HTML elements have a class dark:bg-... specified, not just a bg-..., else that will be the result. If you are missing the dark class, it will only read the standard bg color.
